Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':restart_app:compileDebugKotlin
Help me.. why does this error always appear every time I want to run a Flutter application on Android?
I'm encountering a persistent issue when trying to run my Flutter application on Android. If I create a new Flutter project, it runs smoothly, but this specific project consistently throws the following error:
Project Details

I have tried both the old and latest versions of the Flutter SDK, but the error remains.
I have also installed JDK 17, updated my JAVA version, and updated Gradle, yet the issue persists.

Here is my build.gradle file located in app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17' // Consider checking if this matches the installed Kotlin version
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.agungdev.music"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}


Please help me immediately.. I have been getting this error for 2 days. I have installed JDK 17, updated JAVA, updated Gradle, but the error still appears.


upgrade  your pubspec.yaml file pub versions .
